# Imposible hacer suite de pruebas con NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Problema al intentar hacer suite de pruebas con NetBeans después de crear las
clases de test de cada clase,al principio si podia dándole el botón derecho sobre el paquete de test-new-test suite pero ahora no sale la opción test suite,he desinstalado la versión 8.2 de NetBeans y vuelto a intalar 8.0 varias veces pero nada,sigo sin poder,lo demás funciona bien pero eso no.
Tengo Junit 3 y 4 en test library está junit 4 pero le añado junit 3 y tampoco,no se si es que hay que eliminar la 4 o que.
Espero que alguien sepa cual puede ser el problema,gracias de antemano.

Comment: He restablecido windows 10 a los valores de fábrica pero sigue sin fucionar el poder hacer una suite de pruebas con NetBeans,es una cosa muy rara,no lo entiendo...tiene el pluging junit incluido al instalarse NetBeans y los test normales si que van bien.

Comment: ...Será un misterio para siempre...